# Kubernetes, how to share read/write persistent volume as read only volume with other nodes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a persistent volume that has read/write access on one specific node.

How can I mount this persistent volume on all other nodes as read only?

Here is what I was thinking, in my pvc.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the PVC. This is used in deployment.
  name: public-pv-claim
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    # This is the request for storage. Should be available in the cluster.
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and in the specific node

```
      ...
      volumes:
      - name: public
        # This volume is based on PVC
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          # Name of the PVC created earlier
          claimName: public-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: specific
        # Volume mounts for this container
        volumeMounts:
        # Volume 'public' is mounted to path '/public'
        - name: data
          mountPath: "/public"
        ...
```

and for pods of other nodes:

```
      ...
      volumes:
      - name: public
        # This volume is based on PVC
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          # Name of the PVC created earlier
          claimName: public-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: other
      ...
      volumeMounts:
      - name: public
        mountPath: "/public"
        readOnly: true
      ...
```

Comment: What storage system do you use?

Comment: Specifying `readOnly: true` in `volumeMounts` in `Pod` specification is the correct approach. Do you experience any issue with it ? This can be specified only in mount options as access modes in PV or PVC definition have completely different function.

Comment: @Jonas. minio..

Comment: @mario yes i use readOnly: true for volumeMounts in Pods as shown in the last snippet of the configuration yaml file i use for pods.

Comment: I think i am getting closer to a good solution by setting accessModes: - ReadWriteMany for the Persistent Volume and readOnly: true for volumeMounts in Pods... very similar to my initial thought... if everything worked well i will post it as an answer

Comment: I think Minio only is Object Storage. Does it support Block Storage as Persistent Volumes?

Comment: I am using the minio kubernetes plugin. https://docs.min.io/minio/k8s/reference/minio-kubectl-plugin.html it seems to me that supports block storage as persistent volumes out of the box.

Comment: @Oussama, any updates ? Have you finally managed to make it work the way you need ?

Comment: Yes I kind of did... I will write the solution I found  in an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was to give the persistance volume the "ReadWriteMany" access modes: and then mount it with readOnly set to true in the definition of mounted volumes. Here are the .yaml files..

The persistent volume claim... pvc.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the PVC. This is used in deployment.
  name: public-pv-claim
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany # All nodes have read/write access to the volume
  resources:
    # This is the request for storage. Should be available in the cluster.
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

and in the specific node that should be allowed to write to the volume container_write_access_to_pv.yaml:

```
  ...
  volumes:
  - name: public
    # This volume is based on PVC
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      # Name of the PVC created earlier
      claimName: public-pv-claim
  containers:
  - name: specific
    # Volume mounts for this container
    volumeMounts:
    # Volume is mounted to path '/public'
    - name: data
      mountPath: "/public"
    ...
```

and for pods of other nodes that should have read only access:
container_with_read_only_access_to_pv.yaml:

```
  ...
  volumes:
  - name: public
    # This volume is based on PVC
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      # Name of the PVC created earlier
      claimName: public-pv-claim
  containers:
  - name: other
  ...
  volumeMounts:
  - name: public
    # Volume is mounted to path '/public' in read-only mode
    mountPath: "/public"
    readOnly: true
  ...
```